# How do I add a Windows Explorer toolbar to Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, toolbar

I just started working with Windows Server 2008 R2 (coming straight from Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP) and I am sadly missing the "Up Folder" button that is so often used from the old Windows Explorer format. I did some research and there are 2 available ways to add it back in to Vista and Windows 7. Technically, there is no reason why they shouldn't also work on Windows Server 2008 R2. Here are the links to the 2 ways of doing this:

- http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/tabbed-explorer-add-on-for-windows-vista-and-an-up-button-too/
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/classicshell/

Both of these packages use a toolbar that is added to Windows Explorer and the instructions tell you to go to View > Toolbars to add the toolbar into Explorer. However, there is no such option as View > Toolbars under Windows Server 2008 R2 (Web Edition). I have hunted through all of the menus, and even tried disabling "Lock the toolbars" which I thought was the right track, but I still don't have an option for adding toolbars.

My question is - is there a way to add toolbars in Windows Explorer of Windows Server 2008 R2?

**NOTE:** I realize the keyboard shortcut ALT + Up Arrow will do the same thing, but when working with Windows Explorer my right hand is normally on the mouse, not the keyboard. To say that the keyboard shortcut is faster is therefore a misnomer.

Answer (score 1):

There was a very similar question discussed recently. See [here](https://superuser.com/questions/289184/windows-explorers-broken-back-and-forward-buttons/289188#289188).

You might be able to use the mouse driver to assign keyboard shortcuts to special mouse buttons. Maybe it would be sufficient for you to assign <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>up</kbd> to a mouse button instead.

Clicking the path components in the address bar is another option of course.